# What does COB stands for when a custom tab is defined for Sharepoint ribbon

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

> UPDATE : Sorry for asking such a silly question

While creating custom tab in sharepoint Ribbon we use ID="COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.CustomTab" in XML.

Please tell me the what does COB stands in above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It stands for "Chris O'Brien". Whoever built your custom tab control followed Chris' Blog post: 
http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/01/customizing-ribbon-part-1-creating-tabs.html

Comment: WTHack but Thanks. I was really confused. So ID can have any value like HTML